# VBA Count Table Rows which Contain data

Tags: excel, vba

Follow on from [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088729/row-count-where-data-exists). I am trying to count the number of rows in a table which contain data (not counting number of rows which are part of the table).

For example, my table is:
[image]

My code is:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ATB = .ListObjects("Table1")
    .Activate
    numberRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With`
```

This returns the wrong number (trust me that column A has the same data count)
[image]

Likewise, I want to use VBA to resize the table nicely but need this row count for that.

Comment: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` the parent there is the worksheet, not your table.

Comment: Use this line instead `numberRows = .Range("A:A").Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`.  If you want more information then see [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub check()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ATB = .ListObjects("Table1")
        .Activate
        numberRows = Application.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this excel formula

```
=COUNTA(Table1[A1])
```