# Find the last row Value VBA inside Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Hello guys, as you can see the column B has formulas that are conected to the column E.
And I would like to find the last row in column B that has a value. In this case it would be row 5 and not row 25.
I used this code: LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
But its not what I want.
Because there are formulas un column B i can´t find the last row which has a value.

```
  |    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |    E     |
 1|Date      |Week      |Product   |Name      |date      |
 2|          |        36|          |          |12.09.2021|
 3|          |        37|          |          |13.09.2021|
 4|          |        43|          |          |25.10.2021|
 5|          |         4|          |          |30.01.2021|
 6|          |          |          |          |          |

25|          |          |          |          |          |

Color fill in A2 .. P25 yellow

Formula in column B5, copies of which are repeated from row 2 to row 25
=IF(E5="";"";TRUNC((E5-DATE(YEAR(E5+3-MOD(E5-2;7));1;MOD(E5-2;7)-9))/7))
```

Comment: I cant see the image, but i tried something like so `range("b1:b9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,2).row-1` on a simple formula, can you show the image in text in the post, not all can access images from sites at work.  Thanks

Comment: Week Product Name Date
36                               12.09.2021
37                               13.09.2021
43                               25.10.2021
4                                 30.01.2021

Comment: Luis, for eventual future needs, to get help from those that can not view images, you can provide something like I did for you above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row count where data exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088729/row-count-where-data-exists)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the formula route, try `=MAX(IF(B:B="",0,ROW(B:B)))`.

Note, this formula could be slow if you are using it a lot.

If you want to use VBA, you could try (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51559438/9393094),

```
Function GetLastRow(col, row)
    ' col and row are where we will start.
    ' We will find the last row for the given column.
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = ""
        row = row + 1
    Loop
    GetLastRow = row
End Function
```