# Populating Combo Box with column

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have been smashing my head through the computer screen trying to solve this but every solution I've found led to nowhere.

I am trying to create a Userform and I want to populate a Combobox with data from the Excel sheet it's connected to. The Sheet is titled as 'PrinterModels (Printer Models)' in the VBA editor, the box is titled as cmbModel. When I populate the box with RowSource in it's properties it populates but when items are selected they disappear from the list when another item is selected. What I need is a way to populate the Box in code and if it acts the same, I need a way to repoplulate the box next time it is messed with. I've posted my latest attempt below which gives error 1004

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'cmbModel.List = PrinterModels.Range("A2:A").Value
    
    ModelLast = PrinterModels.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
    
    For i = 1 To ModelLast
    Value = PrinterModels.Cells(i, 1).Value
    cmbModel.AddItem Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set the rowsource to a range on a sheet? I fought with this recently and that's how I resolved it. If you need to add items then add them to the list on the sheet and update the resource with the expanded range.

Comment: `x1Up` should be `xlUp`  You can avoid this type of error almost completely by using `Option explicit`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I found an answer after continuing to hunt deeper and found a solution here [StackOverflow 18088729](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088729/row-count-where-data-exists)

After changing the answer code to the following, the Box filled the way I wanted.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'cmbModel.List = PrinterModels.Range("A2:A").Value
    With PrinterModels
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To LastRow
    myValue = PrinterModels.Cells(i, 1).Value
    cmbModel.AddItem myValue
    Next i
End Sub
```